# How do I define Sheep in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am reading [this monad tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/All_About_Monads#An_example). I am trying to implement `Sheep` that will work with this tutorial.

I tried this

```
-- No Sheep or Name, Father Sheep, Mother Sheep
data Sheep = Nothing | String Sheep Sheep
```

but it isn't working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first part of a constructor definition is the name of the constructor. The types of its arguments come after that. Also if a constructor has no argument, the name isn't followed by anything, so no "Nothing". So if we were to name your constructors "NoSheep" and "Sheep", it would be:

```
data Sheep = NoSheep | Sheep String Sheep Sheep
```

Answer (score 2):

sepp2k translated your specifications correctly, but the tutorial says something different than you:

> We would certainly want to know the genetic history of all of our
>   sheep, so we would need mother and father functions. But since these
>   are cloned sheep, they may not always have both a mother and a father!

The easiest way would be:

```
data Sheep = Sheep String (Maybe Sheep) (Maybe Sheep)
```

But I think the recod syntax would be clearer here, and give you the necessary methods for free:

```
data Sheep = Sheep { name :: String
                   , mother :: Maybe Sheep
                   , father :: Maybe Sheep
                   }
```

However this allows the possibility that a sheep has *neither* mother *nor* father. The easiest way to avoid this possibility would be to simply enumerate all cases:

```
data Sheep = SheepWithMother String Sheep 
           | SheepWithFather String Sheep
           | SheepWithMotherAndFather String Sheep Sheep

mother (SheepWithMother _ m) = Just m
mother (SheepWithMotherAndFather _ m _) = Just m
mother _ = Nothing

father (SheepWithFather _ f) = Just f
father (SheepWithMotherAndFather _ _ f) = Just f
father _ = Nothing
```

You could also use the `Or` data type defined here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-or/1.0.0/doc/html/Data-Or.html

```
data Sheep = Sheep Int (Or Sheep Sheep)
```

Similar to our own version, `Or a b` has the three constructors `Fst a`, `Snd b` and `Both a b`.